# Facebook Opengraph customize fb login button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm using facebook open graph, new api, and i can do this:

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" max-rows="9" perms="email" autologoutlink="true" onlogin="window.location = 'http://www.example.com/facebook/facebook_test/'"></fb:login-button>
```

but when i read the doc if i need more options in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login says i can:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
    if (response.perms) {
      // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
      // perms is a comma separated list of granted permissions
    } else {
      // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions
    }
  } else {
    // user is not logged in
  }
}, {perms:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
```

but if i need another image for fb button, and if i need another things, i can't find how do that, of in what part of html i can call FB.login, is between tags 'script'?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to use [Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) for this. Just wrap that `FB.login` into some function and call it wherever you want. For example if you want to call it on image click:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
          //initializing API
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
                     xfbml: true});
          };
          (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
              '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
          }());
        </script>

        <!-- custom login button -->
        <a href="#" onclick="fblogin();return false;"><img src="images/my_login.png"></a>


        <script>
          //your fb login function
          function fblogin() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
              //...
            }, {scope:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
          }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note that starting today you would need to enable OAuth2.0, FB is disabling this type of login. For more info visit [This Facebook Blog Post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/)

Comment: The above code is not outdated and work perfectly if you want to avoid the fb:login-button